# Delete from a table where aa<>aa from another database

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having some troubles with an SQL request.

I've 2 database, with the same table (structure, not content)

I want to delete all the rows from database1, when two of their fields doesn't correspond to the ones in database2.

for exemple :
d1.table.field1 != d2.table.field1 and d1.table.field2 != d2.table.field2 -> delete this row
else, don't.

Now, here is my actual (not working) code :

```
DELETE
FROM table
WHERE table.field1 NOT IN (SELECT table.field1 FROM table@database2)
AND table.field2 NOT IN (SELECT table.field2 FROM table@database2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are matching `field1` and `field2` from different rows. If the idea is that both fields must come from the same row, this should work:

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM table@database2 tt
    WHERE tt.field1=table.field1 AND tt.field2=table.field2
)
```

The condition of the `SELECT` in `NOT EXISTS` ensures that the pair `field1, field2` must belong to the same row in `database2`'s table.

Comment: Another option would have been `where (field1, field2) not in (select field1, field2 from table@database2)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Right, Oracle lets you do this. I haven't been using Oracle for more than six years now, so I started to forget. Thanks!

Comment: Not only Oracle. That syntax is defined by the SQL standard and is also supported by Postgres, DB2 and (suprisingly) MySQL (maybe even more)